# Prove that there is at least one excellent contestant

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, induction

> Consider a tournament in which each contestant plays every other
>   contestant exactly once, and one of them wins. We’ll say that a
>   contestant $x$ is excellent if, for every other contestant $y$, either $x$
>   beats $y$ or there is a third contestant $z$ such that $x$ beats $z$ and $z$
>   beats $y$. Prove that there is at least one excellent contestant.

My attempt:

By induction.

**Base case:**

Two contestants. Clearly one of them wins, hence there will be an excellent contestant

**Induction step:**

Suppose for $n$ contestants, there will be an excellent contestant.

Now consider arbitrary $n+1$ contestants. Remove arbitrary contestant, say **Bob**.

Then for remaining $n$ contestants, by inductive hypothesis, there will be at least one excellent contestant, say **Eva**.

Now consider Eva and Bob.

Suppose Eva beats Bob. Then Eva remains an excellent contestant among $n+1$ players.

Suppose Bob beats Eva.

Since Bob wins, we have two scenarios

> 1. Exists contestant $X$ such that Eva beats $X$ and $X$ beats Bob.

In this case, Eva will remain an excellent contestant.

> 2. There doesn't exist contestant $X$, such that Eva beats $X$ and $X$ beats Bob.

Take arbitrary contestant $X$. We have three options

1. Eva beats X and X loses to Bob
2. Eva loses to X and X beats Bob
3. Eva loses to X and X loses to Bob

It can be seen that in option 1 and 3 Bob beats $X$. Now we need to consider second option.

Since Eva is an excellent contestant among $n$ players and she loses to $X$, exists $Y$ such that Eva beats $Y$ and $Y$ beats $X$.

Consider Bob and $Y$. We know that either Bob beats $Y$ or Y beats Bob.

By assumption we made above ("There doesn't exist contestant $X$, such that Eva beats $X$ and $X$ beats Bob. ") we conclude that Bob beats $Y$.

So in this case, for arbitrary contestant $X$, either Bob beats $X$, or exists $Y$ such that Bob beats $Y$ and $Y$ beats $X$. Hence Bob will be an excellent contestant.

Therefore, in any case, there will be at least one excellent contestant among $n+1$ players. (Either Eva or Bob)

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: It looks correct, but is much more convoluted than it needs to be. You are on the right track about considering Bob and Eva in those 2 scenarios.

Comment: @bof Yes, the extremal principle is a good way too. For such proof verification questions, I generally prefer to keep the proof along the lines that OP is thinking (where possible)

Comment: Your proof is fine. Here's another way to prove it by induction. Assuming it's true for tournaments with $\lt n$ contestants, we prove it for a tournament $T$ with $n$ contestants. Call one player Bob. If Bob beat all the others, we're done. Otherwise, consider the tournament $U$ consisting of the $m$ players who beat Bob, $0\lt m\lt n$. By the inductive hypothesis, U has an excellent contestant, call her Eve. Now it's easy to see that Eve is also an excellent contestant in the bigger tournament $T$.

Comment: Without induction: Suppose Max has the maximum number of wins. If Bob is any player who beat Max, then, since Max has at least as many wins as Bob, Max must have beaten some player that Max didn't beat, i.e., Max beat some player who beat Bob.